# How can i see multiple pins in maps in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I want to see multiple pins in maps when i open google map.
I used this link as help https://xamarinforms.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/adding-a-bindable-map-with-the-map-behavior/

but i get error in MapBehaviour.cs.here is my code.`

BindableProperty.Create>(
        p => p.ItemsSource, null, BindingMode.Default, null, ItemsSourceChanged);//i get error in this page

```
public  class MapBehavior: BindableBehavior<Map>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MapBehavior, IEnumerable<ILocationViewModel>>(
    p => p.ItemsSource, null, BindingMode.Default, null, ItemsSourceChanged);

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ILocationViewModel> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<ILocationViewModel>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        var behavior = bindable as MapBehavior;
        if (behavior == null) return;
        behavior.AddPins();
    }

    private void AddPins()
    {
        var map = AssociatedObject;
        for (int i = map.Pins.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            map.Pins[i].Clicked -= PinOnClicked;
            map.Pins.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        var pins = ItemsSource.Select(x =>
        {
            var pin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.SearchResult,
                Position = new Position(x.Latitude, x.Longitude),
                Label = x.Title,
                Address = x.Description,

            };

            pin.Clicked += PinOnClicked;
            return pin;
        }).ToArray();

        foreach (var pin in pins)
            map.Pins.Add(pin);

        PositionMap();
    }

    private void PinOnClicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var pin = sender as Pin;
        if (pin == null) return;
        var viewModel = ItemsSource.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == pin.Label);
        if (viewModel == null) return;
        viewModel.Command.Execute(null);
    }

    private void PositionMap()
    {
        if (ItemsSource == null || !ItemsSource.Any()) return;

        var centerPosition = new Position(ItemsSource.Average(x => x.Latitude), ItemsSource.Average(x => x.Longitude));

        var minLongitude = ItemsSource.Min(x => x.Longitude);
        var minLatitude = ItemsSource.Min(x => x.Latitude);

        var maxLongitude = ItemsSource.Max(x => x.Longitude);
        var maxLatitude = ItemsSource.Max(x => x.Latitude);

        var distance = MapHelper.CalculateDistance(minLatitude, minLongitude,
            maxLatitude, maxLongitude, 'M') / 2;

        AssociatedObject.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(centerPosition, Distance.FromMiles(distance)));

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), () =>
        {
            AssociatedObject.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(centerPosition, Distance.FromMiles(distance)));
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 1.BindableBehavior<Map> could not be found.Which namespace is need to add?                                                                                                                     2.the type cannot be used as parameter TDeclarer in the generic type or method BindableProperty.Create<TDeclarer,TPropertyType>

Comment: The blog post is rather old so I would recommend to start with a simple map example and expand from that. You can do this, for example, with an custom MapRenderer.